# face_recognition library taking to much time to execute, I also tried to use Numba but I'm unable to execute, How to optimize following code?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, face-recognition, numba

the `face_encoding` contain the embedding of 13 person, and it's taking near about 9sec to execute following method

`emb` and `face_encoding`  have the data type numpy.ndarray array

```
def face_match(emb, face_encoding):

    face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(emb, face_encoding)
    
    return face_distances
```

I also tried following code where I used Numba, but I'm unable to find where I'm going wrong

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def face_match(emb, face_encoding):

    face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(emb, face_encoding)

    return face_distances
```

I also tried to use `@njit(nopython=True)` but still it's not working

Answer (score 0):

The time it takes is up to the implementation of that library.

To make the library faster, you have to change the code of the library. If the library uses `numpy` or `scipy` then the speed could depend on which linear-algebra packages are available on your system.

`Numba` can compile a subset of pure python and numpy (no python lists for example), and to use `@njit` disallows any non-compilable parts of the function. So that definitely should not work.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use deepface? It is keras based library. That's why, it is very easy to install and run.

```
#!pip install deepface
from deepface import DeepFace
resp = DeepFace.verify("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg")
print(resp["verified"])
```

Its default face recognition model is VGG-Face but it wraps also Google FaceNet, OpenFace, Facebook DeepFace, DeepID, Dlib and ArcFace.

```
models = ['VGG-Face', 'Facenet', 'OpenFace', 'DeepFace', 'DeepID', 'Dlib', 'ArcFace']
resp = DeepFace.verify("img1.jpg", "img2.jpg", model_name = models[1])
```

Besides, if you want to find an identity in a database, it has a custom find function.

```
DeepFace.find("img1.jpg", db_path = 'C:/my_db')
```

Here, you are expected to store facial images (.jpg or .png) in my_db folder. Find function returns the same identity images of img1 here.

Comment: thankyou, for the suggestion I will try this and let you know. actually I'm saving the array of 128 given by face-recognition into DB, I'm creating the array of frame and saving  this array into 'emb' , and I'm taking 'face_encoding' from DB. I appended array of of all the people whose registration I did earlier so that I can use this later.  I think now you get what I'm actually doing. so what you think what should I do?

Comment: You can extract embeddings with deepface as well. Please read its documentation. model = 
DeepFace.build_model("Facenet"); embedding = model.predict(img);